# Differecences between "A continuación" vs "dentro de un rato" vs "luego"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, tiempo

> ¿Qué van a echar a las 6 de la tarde?
>
> No sé, pero esto es lo que puedes ver [a continuación / dentro de un rato / luego].

What is the the difference between these three options?
Which ones would refer to "next program relatively to now" and which "relatively to 6pm"?
I need two versions of answers; one which would say what is on tv in a moment from "now" and the other that would say what is on tv after 6pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No sé, pero esto es lo que puedes ver **a continuación**

I would use this if we are close to 6pm and I know that, for example, the current movie is ending and the new program will start at 6pm. It basically means "It is **what comes next**".

The expression "dentro de un rato" means in a while. It's not yet 6pm, so you'll be able to see it in a while.

> No sé, pero esto es lo que puedes ver **luego**.

"Luego" here means "later". It doesn't necessarily mean "later at 6pm" but "later today" or "later this week" (luego, *en algún momento*).